# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast > to org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am using UDF to extract data from a HIVE table .My source hive table has columns in json ,in my UDF I am parsing the json and getting the value . But the query fails posting :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast
>   to org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.write(ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:645)

"

Complete error message :

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:283)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1595)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.write(ParquetRecordWriterWrapper.java:88)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:645)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:87)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:793)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.internalForward(CommonJoinOperator.java:638)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.genAllOneUniqueJoinObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:670)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.CommonJoinOperator.checkAndGenObject(CommonJoinOperator.java:754)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.JoinOperator.endGroup(JoinOperator.java:256)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:216)
>       ... 7 more